# PHP/Laravel How to include one function into another?

Tags: php, laravel, function

Is there a way I can include(?) one function into another? For example, the same way we can include files using include function.
Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean with include a function into another? Do you want to call one from another?

Comment: by `include` do you mean call another function from other function?

Comment: I meant call one from another. I am new to this. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

class test{

    public function message1(){

        $message = 'i am in message1 function';
        return $message;
    }

    public function message2(){

        $message = $this->message1();
        echo $message;
    }
}
```

Functions can not be "included" like you mean but you can call them and use their returned values to other functions like below.

Now if you try to call the `message2` function using something like:

```
$messageClass = new test();

echo $messageClass->message2();
```

you will see that the output is the `$message` from function `message1`

Comment: Why can't functions be included?

Comment: The including/requiring system applies to files/classes not to functions. I mean you can't include a specific function in a php file from another but you can include the file that the function is in, instantiate the class and access the function. Even if the function is static still you can't include it like the OP defines include like `require 'message1()'` Please correct me if i am wrong cause you got me thinking.

Comment: I thought you meant you cannot define a function or include a file that defines functions in a function. And you can, that's why I asked. It seems you are talking about methods, not functions, and that is probably the cause of my confusion :-)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean `callback` function? If so, this is how to use it:

```
// This is callback function which will passed as argument to another function.
function callbackFunction1 ($str) {
    return strtoupper($str);
}


function mainFunction ($offeredCallback, $str) {
    echo( "(" . $offeredCallback($str) . ")<br>");
}

mainFunction("callbackFunction1", "foo");
// Output "(foo)".

// If you want to use Variable Function, define it like this:
$callbackFunction2 = function  ($str) {
    return strtoupper($str);
};

mainFunction($callbackFunction2, "bar");
// Output "(bar)".
```

About Variable Function, see [Anonymous Function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php).